# increase or decrease quantity in list of products

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of products with plus or minus input buttons on each item to control the quantity.

What's the best way to handle the changing of the quantity functionality? When a quantity button is pressed the label displaying the current quantity should reflect the change.

Comment: Provide some html and controller code to see what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunkr with the scenario you described

http://plnkr.co/edit/WCrvWl471AMqjyq1yl3m?p=preview

HTML Code

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <p>{{item.quantity}}</p>
    <a class="button" ng-click="increaseItemCount(item)">+</a>
    <a class="button" ng-click="decreaseItemCount(item)">-</a>
  </div>
  <p> TOTAL</p>
```

Controller Code

```
    $scope.itemList = [{
    "name": "item1",
    "quantity": "0"
  }, {
    "name": "item2",
    "quantity": "0"
  }, {
    "name": "item3",
    "quantity": "0"
  }];
  $scope.increaseItemCount = function(item) {
    item.quantity++;
  };
  $scope.decreaseItemCount = function(item) {
    if (item.quantity > 0) {
      item.quantity--;
    }

  };
  $scope.sumCalc = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.itemList, function(item, index) {
      sum += parseInt(item.quantity,10);
    });
    return sum;
  };
```